# Unit tests with RSpec on the Ruby: "No test report files were found. Configuration error?"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jenkins, rspec

I need to run unit tests with RSpec on the Ruby project that runs on Jenkins.

At this moment there is no code in the project, it's just a vanilla project. So I add a dummy test:

*test_example.rb:*

```
describe Hash do
  it "should return a blank instance" do
Hash.new.should == {}
  end
end
```

My *Gemfile*:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
# Use postgres as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. 
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
 # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
 gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
 # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
 gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
 gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Adds support for RSpec - <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE IS MY CHANGES
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.7.1'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

And add the link on new test file in the *Rakefile:*

```
require_relative 'config/application'
Rails.application.load_tasks

require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.libs << "test"
  t.test_files = FileList['test/test_example.rb']
  t.verbose = true
end
```

Of course, I add the test step in my *Jenkinsfile*:

```
stage("test") {
            junit keepLongStdio: true, testResults: 'rspec/reports/**/*.xml' 
       }
```

But when I run the build, I see this error:

[image]

[image]

**What am I doing wrong?**
I'm sorry I'm a little bit confused that I have so many steps and the problem can be everywhere... I don't know where should I search

Comment: You can delete the first `gem 'rspec-rails'` (line 12) as you already added it to your development and test groups.

Comment: @ogirginc, thanks, done

Answer (score 0):

You're using ruby's test-unit testing framework for that example test, yet you're using the ci_reporter_rspec gem to generate test report xmls. rspec and test-unit are not compatible testing frameworks, and the gem you've chosen will not generate test report xmls for test-unit. You either need to write rspec tests or use the [ci_reporter](https://github.com/ci-reporter/ci_reporter) gem.

Comment: Thank for your answer! I'm trying to use rspec test, I have excluded ci-reporter. But I'm still missing something and have the same error. I have edited my files in the post